# 3-way switch AND sgl pole dimmer in one gang

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I have a problem...I only have room for a single gang box.  Currently a 3-way switch resides there.  We need to add a single pole, dimmer switch to the box.  Isn't there a fan switch that would house what I need?  BTW, the dimmer is going to supply voltage to undercabinet LED lights.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to get any dimmer. You need a dimmer that is compatible with your LED system.  That's a hard find, and diy.se is not a shop-for-me site.  We can help with how to navigate the limitations of the available tech.

Very often these [under-cabinet LED lights](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/kitchen/16282/) are 12 volts from a power supply.   If so, that is the place to do the dimming - after the power supply, on the 12 volt side, with a dimmer for that purpose.  Especially if you want to [jazz it up with RGB LEDs](https://www.superbrightleds.com/cat/controllers/filter/Volts_Typical,12,100,3898:) or [variable color temperature](https://www.superbrightleds.com/cat/variable-white/) LEDs.  Have the switch just be a switch, and have a separate LED-optimized dimmer control under the cabinets where practical.

That will make finding the right switch a lot easier.  All you need is a [duplex 3-way switch](http://amzn.to/1N1Eln2).  A 3-way switch can substitute for a 2-way switch.  Just use the "common" and one other terminal, leave the other terminal unused.